# How to return json data in Dataset<Row> with encoder(structType) in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I tried to return required parameter in DataSet. Whenever am return the data to row am not able to encode the data with struct Type,If suppose am using `Map/JSONObject`  it was throwing `Map/jsonobject it not a valid External schema`, Below code i tried? Any help will be appreciate thanks in advance

```java
DataSet<Row>//
Row rowdat=RowFactory.create(jsondata)
Return rowdat.iterator();

//Dataset data will be **** [[{"employees:"accountant","firstname":"walter", "age":"54"}]]


StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("employees",  DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("firstname", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, true)

    });

ExpressionEncoder express=RowCoder.apply(schema)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You don't usually (always?) use Spark to create rows from a custom type. It's Spark's job (no pun intended). Describe the task at hand in more details.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski In dataset am tried to return 40 fields but in my input i have 100 field So i used mappartitions and I was returning 40 fields alone in row factory.. but i need to return key value pair of data instead of Row [ ] values..??

Comment: Why don't you simply `select` with the required 40 cols?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski if am using mappartitions it will process the whole partition data, for parallel processing I used that one